# Optimize the filtering of Queryset results in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm overriding [`Django Admin's list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) (to customize the filter that shows on the right side on the django admin UI for a listview). The following code works, but isn't optimized: it increases SQL queries by "number of product categories".

(The parts to focus on, in the following code sample are, `qs.values_list('product_category', flat=True)` which only returns an `id` (int), so I've to use `ProductCategory.objects.get(id=i)`.)

Wondering if this can be simplified?

(E.g. data:  Suppose the product categories are "baked" "fried" "raw" etc., and the Items are "bread" "fish fry" "cake". So when the Item list is displayed in Django Admin, all product categories will show on the 'Filter By' column on the right side of the UI.)

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter
from product_category.model import ProductCategory


class ProductCategoryFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('ProductCategory')
    parameter_name = 'product_category'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)

        ordered_filter_obj_list = []
        # TODO: Works, but increases SQL queries by "number of product categories"
        for i in (
            qs.values_list("product_category", flat=True)
            .distinct()
            .order_by("product_category")
        ):
            cat = ProductCategory.objects.get(id=i)
            ordered_filter_obj_list.append((i, cat))

        return ordered_filter_obj_list

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(product_category__exact=self.value())



# P.S. Above filter is used in another class like so
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (ProductCategoryFilter,)
```

Comment: You could provide your models too so that other people might give you an advice about how to design a schema to match with your need and to mitigate the db queries

Comment: The model code isn't really necessary, will make the question too lengthy. (Got the answers already)

Comment: Yeah, just thinking out loud, because if your model have relational together then select_related will be a better choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah, phrasing the question makes it clear in your own head! Found an answer mins after posting this:

(Instead of doing an `objects.get()` inside the `for` loop, we can do `objects.all()` (which is a single SQL Query) and fill up a temporary dictionary. Then use this temp dict to find the associated string value.)

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)

    category_list = {}
    for x in ProductCategory.objects.all():
        category_list[x.id] = str(x)

    ordered_filter_obj_list = []
    for i in (
        qs.values_list("product_category", flat=True)
        .distinct().order_by("product_category")
    ):
        ordered_filter_obj_list.append((i, category_list[i]))

    return ordered_filter_obj_list
```

Comment: You could do this also: `ordered_filter_obj_list = [(i, category_list[i]) for i in qs.values_list("product_category", flat=True)]`, list comprehension might make you wow in some cases

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), I do not know your exact models structure, but you may use it as follow:

```
cats = set()

for p in Product.objects.all().select_related('category'):
    # Without select_related(), this would make a database query for each
    # loop iteration in order to fetch the related categories  for each product.
    cats.add(p.category)
```

I am Assuming there is some relation between your Product and `ProductCategory` models. Hope this help.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to respond! I found the answer. Yup, instead of using `objects.get()` inside a loop, doing `objects.all()` outside the for loop and storing in a data structure is the direction I also took.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter on the tuple list is the value of the lookup, and the second is just the name for display. This can be done in a single SQL query, or via the Django ORM:

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
  qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request).select_related('product_category')
  values = qs.values('product_category_id', 'product_category__name') #assuming ProductCategory has an attribute 'name'
  unique_categories = values.distinct('product_category_id', 'product_category__name')
  categories = []
  for c in unique_categories:
    categories.append((c['product_category_id'], c['product_category__name']))
  return categories
```

Comment: Hey, seems to be a good direction but I'm unable to get it to run. Keeps telling me this: `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions` . Found a solution anyway. Thanks.